# Helm deploy takes long time when there are many running Pods

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, helm, kubernetes-helm, google-kubernetes-engine

Topics:

- Helm deployments
- helm timeout
- kubernetes HPA tuning
- kubernetes min/max replicas tuning
- kubernetes HPA threshold tuning

I'm running Kubernetes in GKE, so if I refer to "Console" -- I mean the GCP GKE web Console.

I am trying to figure out how to adjust my deployment so that it returns more quickly on new deploys, especially when there are many Pods. For example, when HPA has bumped the desired number up to a high number.

I have a HorizontalPodAutoscaler that I think probably tuned poorly; however, I'd like to start with the assumption that it is tuned fine, and solve the problem where deployments take a very long time when there are a lot of running Pods.

When the number of Pods is large helm takes a long time to "figure out" that the deployment was successful. Even though the console, and kubectl commands, report the ready state of the Pods as "OK"

For example, deploy when pods "desired" is at 6 or so takes about 3 minutes.

However, deploy when pods "desired" is at 100 takes over 19 minutes.

Any given Pod returns an "OK" healthcheck just as quickly, no matter how many Pods are desired, or running.

- How do I get helm to return as "ok" when only a fixed number of Pods is reporting OK?
- How do I get helm to determine that pods are "ok" more quickly?

Currently my solution is to add `--timeout=20m0s` to the helm command. This isn't a very good solution.